# This webpage has a redirect loop

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I have transfer my site from one domain to another. I have cleared cache & session as well. No htaccess issue. URL changed in database.

Still it redirects to

`<my domain>/downloader/downloader` & giving error This webpage has a redirect loop

Any idea what still i need to check?

Comment: Do you have multiple site configuration  ?

Comment: Most probably this is an access rights issue. Make sure the files are readable.

Comment: Solved. Some files are missing in upload. Thanks

Comment: @test please add the solution as an answer to the question. thanks